# BTZ Black holes

Tags: black-holes, correlation-functions, propagator, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I computed the two point function for two scalar fields in BTZ black hole that is defined as a local $AdS_3$ space time with discrete identification, as defined in many papers. Referring to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9808037), I found the result in (28) but to implement the identification we have to sum over all the images. But it seems that in the result (34) of the two point function found from the propagator (28) he didn't perform the summation. This happens also in other references. Why I can't see the summation?

Comment: Your question is likely to get much more answers/attention if you include the relevant information from the linked paper.